# Tkinter crashing ArcMap from Python Add-In

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, tkinter

ArcMap crashes every time I try to display a form using tkinter from my python add-in button.

Are there any updated workarounds for this?

I saw this from before, but couldn't get it to work:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212848/108211

Has anyone figured out a way to make this work, or are there any other python GUI's that will work with python addins?