# ArcMap stops working when I click on add-in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, python-2.7, python-addin

First creating the form with a tkinter. as in the code below.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

class RestServis:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("REST SERVİS EKLE")
        #setting window size
        width=653
        height=170
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        GLabel_566=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Lucida Sans Unicode',size=8)
        GLabel_566["font"] = ft
        GLabel_566["fg"] = "#1e9fff"
        GLabel_566["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_566["text"] = "Kullanıcı Adı:"
        GLabel_566.place(x=19,y=15,width=76,height=15)

        GLabel_869=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Lucida Sans Unicode',size=8)
        GLabel_869["font"] = ft
        GLabel_869["fg"] = "#1e9fff"
        GLabel_869["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_869["text"] = "Şifre:"
        GLabel_869.place(x=19,y=46,width=36,height=15)

        GLabel_21=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Lucida Sans Unicode',size=8)
        GLabel_21["font"] = ft
        GLabel_21["fg"] = "#1e9fff"
        GLabel_21["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_21["text"] = "Servis Link:"
        GLabel_21.place(x=19,y=79,width=67,height=15)


        GButton_510=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_510["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Lucida Sans Unicode',size=8)
        GButton_510["font"] = ft
        GButton_510["fg"] = "#ff0000"
        GButton_510["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_510["text"] = "Listele"
        GButton_510.place(x=543,y=75,width=75,height=23)
        GButton_510["command"] = self.GButton_510_command

        GLabel_634=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_634["font"] = ft
        GLabel_634["fg"] = "#999999"
        GLabel_634["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_634["text"] = "Örn: https://myportal/rest/services/ServisName/ServisType"
        GLabel_634.place(x=152,y=107,width=336,height=15)

        text=tk.Text(root).place(x=104, y=9, width=125, height=24)

        text1=tk.Text(root).place(x=104, y=42, width=125, height=24)

        text2=tk.Text(root).place(x=104, y=76, width=433, height=24)

    def GButton_510_command(self):
        print("command")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = RestServis(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I made this code in a separate py file then I added it to C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\arcpy in this path to import
I created a button with the add-in wizard, then I called this form above.
When the following code sample button is clicked, this form comes.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

import tkinter as tk
from RestServisButton import RestServis


class Rest(object):
    """Implementation for Tool_Cbs_addin.Rest (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
            root = tk.Tk()
            restApp = RestServis(root)
            root.mainloop()
```

The error occurs when I click the button I created, the ArcMap application closes itself.
Footnote: I installed the tkinter library as 2.7 version externally. I don't know if ArcMap supports this.

error code
[image]

Comment: Tkinter is not compatible with ArcMap https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/212722/2856

Comment: so if i want to make a form how do i do it

Comment: Some people have reported PyQT/PySide could work, but when I used to work with ArcMap (not for a long time, I now only use ArcGIS Pro) I did this by creating a script tool which makes use of the built in geoprocessing tool dialogs and then using `pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(toolbox, tool_name)` to show that tool dialog from the add-in.

Comment: Thank's for the information. I will try a GPToolDialog